# Loop fails to work after input validation added

Tags: python, loops, validation

```
def Data():
    while True:
        try:
            PetTotal = int(input("Please enter the number of pets: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
            continue
        else:
            PetBreeds = []
            Ages = []
            while True:
                try:
                    Gender = int(input("Enter gender option: ")) 
                except ValueError:
                    print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
                    continue
                if Gender > 2 or Gender < 1:
                    print("Wrong!")
                    continue
                else:
                    Count = 0
                    while Count != PetTotal:
                        Breed = str(input("Breed: "))
                        Age = float(input("Age: ")) 
                        if Gender == 1:
                            PetBreeds.append(Breed)
                            Ages.append(Age)
                            Count = Count + 1
                        else:
                            PetBreeds.append(Breed)
                            Ages.append(Age)
                            Count = Count + 1
                        PetInfo = dict(zip({PetBreeds, Ages))
                        return PetBreeds, Gender;
```

I have added some input validation to my code as I am trying to understand it. However, my code no longer works properly. When `PetTotal` is above 2, it only loops once so that only one pet type can be entered (rather than two). I'm sure the answer is obvious but I can't figure it out...any help is greatly welcomed!

Comment: you're `return`ing from the function, "breaking" the outermost loop. instead, push into a list and return after the list's length equals `PetTotal`

Comment: @TylerSebastian Thanks for your response. Could you please clarify a bit further?

Comment: Your code would be more readable to others if you follow python naming conventions. Only class names should start with an uppercase letter. Function names and other variables use `snake_case`.

Comment: Try to avoid multiple levels of nested code. A function should have a single job. Here you do lots of stuff. You make sure that `Gender` is a number, but later on you don't do the same for `Age`. This will break if the user inputs an age that can't be parsed as a float. You could instead extract this task into a function called `input_valid` and call it like so `age = input_valid(float, 'your age?')` or `gender = input_valid(int, 'your integral gender?')`

Answer (score 1):

The else part will execute only once irrespective of the value entered in try case, so try to apply a for loop so that the else part is executed n number of times

```
for i in range(0,PetTotal):
    #else part here
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Which line number would you insert it in?

Comment: After line 8 (else : )

Answer (score 1):

the final line in your method `return`s - which will cause the outermost loop (the one controlling how many pets to process) to exit.

I think you want your code to look similar to

```
pets = []
total = input("...")

while len(pets) < total:
# or `for i in range(0, total):` as in Keshav's answer
  pet = { }

  ... # process input for gender, age, etc

  pets.append(pet)
```

Comment: exactly - it's a list of dicts where each dict holds information about a pet